# Best circuit to turn on a (5v heating pad) switch during the day?

Tags: mosfet, ldr, photoresistor

Most of the circuit examples I'm finding online for LDR or other light-detecting circuits appear to be for turning things on at night. I'm trying to rig up a small heating pad under a birdbath using a 5v heating pad (about 3ohms/8W) tied to a 2C thermal switch.

I plan on powering it from a 5v power pack with a small solar charger. But since birds don't really come at night (and since it is colder at night), I'm wondering if there's a way to build a simple off-at-night switch using something like a mosfet. I'm EE challenged, haven't worked a lot with LDRs and don't want to resort to an Arduino solution if I don't have to.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

FYI, in my parts bin I have a mix of mosfets available such as IRF520, IRF530, IRF540 and a few smaller types like 2n7000 and BS250. Healthy assortment of xsistors (2n3904, 2n3906, 2n2222, and an assortment of B*)
I even have some relays, but would prefer as simple a circuit as possible and can buy more parts if needed.
I found some gl5537 ldrs, but can get something else if need be also.

Comment: Won't adding an inverter (another transistor to invert the logic) help?

Comment: Using a photo transistor is better than LDR.

Answer (score 2):

I won't claim that this is the best circuit, but here is *a* circuit.

None of the transistors that you listed are up to the task. The MOSFETs have a marginally high Vgs thresholds. The BJTs have low max collector currents.

You want a circuit with hysteresis, without it, you may stress the transistor when you oscillate near the switching point. Adding hysteresis is easy with a comparator (LM339).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP7GoD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The threshold at the comparator is about 1.2V. The heater will activate when the LDR resistance is less than about 100k with the values shown.

Change R7 to change the light sensitivity. R5 adds hysteresis (small positive feedback). The MOSFET is a logic-level MOSFET. This one should be available in a hobbyist friendly package.

C1 should be mounted close to the comparator. Don't forget to add decoupling caps near the comparator.

The comparator will draw a few milliamps. I don't know if that is low enough to be negligible for your battery. If not, there are lower power comparators. You could also increase R6 to 100k to save a little power also.

Comment: thanks! Something to play with is better than little or nothing!